# Linux Web Kiosk which boots faster

Tags: linux-distributions, kiosk

Here is the scenario. I've to build a cheap kiosk that should show a specific website only. Since its a web kiosk i dont think there will be a need of powerful processor or HDD.. So i have an idea of going for Intel Atom Kit and boot some linux from a flash drive or flash card.

And when powered on the kiosk must boot within 5 seconds and load Opera in kiosk mode. Opera is good in kiosk mode so i've chosen that. If there is anything good than opera please do suggest.

I've seen some linux which boots in 2 seconds([Moblin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdmbVsqYjdc) now meego). But these couldn't be modded for web kiosk.

Which linux is best for my requirement. i.e

- Bootup in 5 seconds.
- Loads a browser automatically after bootup with a specific website alone.
- Allows Multi Touch or single touch input (OPTIONAL)

Comment: 5 seconds?  I dont think Ive ever seen anything boot that fast... not that it cant be done... still the video you linked took 14 seconds to go from post till the screen loaded.

Answer (score 2):

ThinKiosk is a very good replacement shell for windows. Ideal for Citrix enviroments etc

Comment: When recommending software, please refer to [this meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/47225).

Answer (score 0):

use R-kiosk addon in Mozilla Firefox it get loaded very fast and works efficiently.

Comment: i need to know some best linux too boot fast and can be modded..!! am not worried about browser..

Comment: Pls try Ubuntu. It boots up very fast and also get shut down very fast

Comment: i need something that boots under 5 seconds. Ubuntu takes time...